# SQL UPDATE error in VB.net and ACCESS

Tags: sql, vb.net

im programming a "Change password" Form on VB.net. This is the code of OK Button:

```
Private Sub BT_CambiaPass_OK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BT_CambiaPass_OK.Click

    Dim strSql As String = "UPDATE Usuario SET Password= ? WHERE NombreUsuario= ? AND Password= ?"
    Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSql, conexion)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password_New", CStr(TB_CambiaPass_NEW.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("NombreUsuario", CStr(NombreUsuario))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password_Old", CStr(TB_CambiaPass_Old.Text))

        Try
            conectarse()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conexion.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Contraseña antigua incorrecta")
            MsgBox(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Using

End Sub
```

The ex.tostring return "Syntax error on instruction UPDATE...", when debug the variables are OK, but where executeNonQuery get this error.

I have anothers functions like this and they run ok. In fact I tryed the SQL instruction "UPDATE Usuario SET Password= "123" WHERE NombreUsuario= "Admin" AND Password= admin" in Access and all goes OK.

I dunno what's wrong...

Sorry about my primitive english!

Comment: Try adding `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text` after the `Using` line.

Comment: What is the object NombreUsuario and where it came from? Regards,

Comment: tried cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text but the same error.

NombreUsuario came from the Login form at the begining of the program. Is a public variable as string, and contains the username. In Debuging the variable is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password is a keyword, so you have to put it in brackets:

```
... "UPDATE Usuario SET [Password]= ? WHERE NombreUsuario= ? AND [Password]= ?"
```